# Jquery Datatables Paging, how to go to next page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I´m trying to implement paging with Datatables.net. Could you please explain to me **how the next page button works**. ATM I get the first page, but cant navigate to to next, on the server side my controller will only get records for the page being displayed (skip & take ...)

My DataTable:

```
$('#calculation-table').DataTable(
            { // set server side processing to true
                bServerSide: true,
                // set controller responsible for sorting and paging
                sAjaxSource: "CalculationTest/AjaxHandler",
                // show processing is happening while getting data
                bProcessing: true,
                iDisplayLength: 15,
                lengthMenu: [[15, 25, 50, -1], [15, 25, 50, "All"]],
                columns: [
                    { data: "BeneficialOwner" },
                    { data: "Account" },
                    { data: "Country" },
                    { data: "Currency" },
                    { data: "Year" },
                    { data: "Updater" }
                ],
                "language": {
                    "search": "",
                    "searchPlaceholder": "Search..."
                }
            });
    });
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult AjaxHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param, DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
        {
            IEnumerable<CalculationDownloadItem> calResList;
            int filteredRecords;
            int totalRecords;
            using (var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory())
            {
                var poolApi = serviceFactory.GetApiServiceCached<IPoolApi>();
                var mainApi = serviceFactory.GetApiServiceCached<IMainApi>();
                List<CalculationResult> calculationResultsList = mainApi.GetCalculationResults(BankId, param.iDisplayLength, param.iDisplayStart, out totalRecords, out filteredRecords);
                calResList = ParseDownloadItems(calculationResultsList, poolApi, mainApi);
                //count = mainApi.CountCalculationResults(BankId);
            }

            var calculationDownloadItems = calResList as CalculationDownloadItem[] ?? calResList.ToArray();
            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = totalRecords,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredRecords,
                aaData = calculationDownloadItems
            },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that you're not using the paging parameters that are sent in the datatables request.  The `JQueryDataTableParamModel ` object should have another 2 properties: `iDisplayLength ` and `iDisplayStart ` which you need to use in your query to handle the paging.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260672/how-to-pass-value-from-controller-to-jquery-datatable) which might help (if you're using LINQ)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following classes:

```
public class DataTableParameters
   {
       public int Draw;
       public int Length;
       public Dictionary<int, DataTableOrder> Order;
       public bool SearchRegex;
       public string SearchValue;
       public int Start;

       private DataTableParameters()
       {
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Retrieve DataTable parameters from WebMethod parameter, sanitized against parameter spoofing
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="input"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       public static DataTableParameters Get(object input)
       {
           return Get(JObject.FromObject(input));
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Retrieve DataTable parameters from JSON, sanitized against parameter spoofing
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="input">JToken object</param>
       /// <returns>parameters</returns>
       public static DataTableParameters Get(JToken input)
       {
           return new DataTableParameters
           {
               Order = DataTableOrder.Get(input),
               Draw = (int)input["parameters"]["draw"],
               Start = (int)input["parameters"]["start"],
               Length = (int)input["parameters"]["length"],
               SearchValue = (string)input["parameters"]["search"]["value"],
               SearchRegex = (bool)input["parameters"]["search"]["regex"]
           };
       }
   }

   public class DataTableOrder
   {
       public int Column;
       public string Direction;

       private DataTableOrder()
       {
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Retrieve the DataTables order dictionary from a JSON parameter list
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="input">JToken object</param>
       /// <returns>Dictionary of Order elements</returns>
       public static Dictionary<int, DataTableOrder> Get(JToken input)
       {
           return (
               (JArray)input["parameters"]["order"])
               .Select(col => new DataTableOrder
               {
                   Column = (int)col["column"],
                   Direction =
                       ((string)col["dir"]).StartsWith("desc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "DESC" : "ASC"
               })
               .ToDictionary(c => c.Column);
       }
   }


public class DataTableResult
   {
       public int draw { get; set; }
       public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
       public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
       public List<CalculationDownloadItem> data { get; set; }
   }
```

then in the AjaxHandler method

```
public DataTableResult AjaxHandler(object parameters)
       {
           var dtparameters = DataTableParameters.Get(parameters);

               string orderBy = getOrderColumn(Convert.ToInt32(dtparameters.Order.FirstOrDefault().Value.Column)) + " " +
                                dtparameters.Order.FirstOrDefault().Value.Direction; //Since the column returned is numeric, you should add a method to get proper order column Name and then append the direction that is returned.
               var startIndex = dtparameters.Start > 0 ? dtparameters.Start / dtparameters.Length : 0;
               var calculationDownloadItems=//This returns from DB

               int TotalRecs = 0;
               if (calculationDownloadItems.Count > 0)
               {
                   TotalRecs = calculationDownloadItems.FirstOrDefault().CountReturnedFromDB;
               }
               var dtResult = new DataTableResult()
               {
                   draw = dtparameters.Draw,
                   recordsFiltered = TotalRecs,
                   recordsTotal = TotalRecs,
                   data = calculationDownloadItems
               };
               return dtResult;
       }
```